# Issue locating elements using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, jquery-easyui

Recently we have ported selenium code to new branch and running it on a new developer build. My observation is that

1. The code runs very slow while locating elements. Specially on Internet explorer.
2. One more issue is that the code is sometimes unable to locate elements. Say 6 out of 1times. I checked the xpaths they seem to be fine, what might be the problem?

I did try debugging and checked if its with xpath/time delay issue, but no luck. However there seems to some changes in the easyUI part thats used for development They are using laest easyUI framework. Will that be the issue? Because the previous version still works better in older dev builds. Will easyUI really affect our automation?

Comment: Can you please share your selenium code? also please manage timeout so it will not fail to find element if xpath is correct.

Comment: I am sure that you might be aware of this. Just FYI, finding an element using the XPATH (absolute/relative) is not a better idea, which degrades the performance and also when the application is under development. You can insist developers to use ID for better performance of locating the elements. For option 2, try to increase the time (in ms) or use a polling logic.

Comment: Its huge code, and the behaviour is not consistent. Seldomly its able to locate. But its not reliable though.Say a simple button or tab with a direct label its not able to locate. Coming to timing, We have provided 2minutes timeout , still its a problem. And the behaviour is not consistent across firefox and Internet explorer. On earlier dev builds, my auto sripts worked fine, latest code i face problem. All the developer has changed is the easyUI framework to build the UI. They are using latest version of easyUI, which we are not sure if its causing error.